# How to set different window(geometry) size for each page?

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I have created two pages using [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) `Frame` widget.

1. I want the first page with geometry size as: `"900x650+220+20"`,
2. and the second page with geometry size as `"1000x800+220+20"`.

Is it possible to do it?

```
from Tkinter import *
def swap_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x650+220+20")
root.title("Testing")
root.configure(borderwidth="1", relief="sunken",cursor="arrow",background="#BCC3B9",highlightcolor="black")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame2 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650)
frame1 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650)


#item 1 spinbox
Platform = Spinbox(frame1, values=("SX-16F", "SX-12VP", "SX-16VP", "VSRM-A", "NRNT-A", "FX-8", "DX-48V"), width="32")
Platform.place(x=500, y=200, relheight=0.05)

Button1=Button(frame1, text="Next", width =10, height= 2, bg= "#dbd8d7", command=lambda:swap_frame(frame2))
Button1.place(x=580, y=580)

Button3=Button(frame2, text="Back", width =10, height= 2, bg= "#dbd8d7", command=lambda:swap_frame(frame1))
Button3.place(x=580, y=580)

frame2.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49271832/4)'s an _entirely_ different issue than the initial question. You should ask separately if so, as opposed to editing the initial question. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the frames call `geometry` method on their `master` in `swap_frame` method:

```
frame.master.geometry("900x650+220+20")
```

or more generally:

```
widget.winfo_toplevel().geometry("100x250+220+20")
```

---

If you want to have *distinct* placements/sizes for each frame, there can be a number of ways of doing that:

1. Collect the frame widgets in a collection type, such as a
   `dict`ionary or a `list`, then call `geometry` with a mapping based
   on the frame
2. Pass the mapping value explicitly, then call `geometry` based on the
   mapping for the *current* frame
3. Have an attribute defined for each frame for mapping or the geometry
   argument directly, and simply call `geometry` using that argument
   for the *current* frame

The example below uses the attributes as suggested in 3:

```
def resize(widget):
    widget.winfo_toplevel().geometry(widget.geo)


def swap_frame(frame):
    resize(frame)
    frame.tkraise()
...
frame1.geo = "900x650+220+20"
frame2.geo = "1000x800+220+20"
```

Comment: I have changed the existing code according to you suggestion, but still seeing frame2 bg in frame1.

`frame2 = Frame(root, width=1200, height=650, bg="green")
frame1 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650)

def resize(widget):
    widget.winfo_toplevel().geometry(widget.geo)


def swap_frame(frame):
    resize(frame)
    frame.tkraise()

frame1.geo = "900x650+220+20"
frame2.geo = "1200x650+220+20"`

Comment: @velpandian The last two lines are _not_ part of any method. They're in the same indentation level as that of your frame instantiations, `frame1 = ...` etc.

Comment: now changed the code in question. I am seeing frame2 background color in frame1 area

Comment: @velpandian Replace frame1.grid(...) with `frame1.grid(..., sticky='nsew')`.